# Error Checking Dynamic Stored Procedure in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic

I have a stored procedure with 3 different `UPDATE` queries.

I want each query to return a value.

If it fails I do not want the procedure to `COMMIT`, I want it to `ROLLBACK` tell me which one of the three stored procedures failed.

I can do it in a non-dynamic but for some reason the same rules don't seem to apply in a dynamic query.

Here is my code and my attempt:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ASP_XXNominalBalanceUPDATE]
     @ORGCODE VARCHAR(6),
     @NewNominal INT,
     @OldNominal INT,
     @BalMonth CHAR(6),
     @Amt Decimal(12,2),
     @FINPERIODNR INT,
     @InvDetailID INT,
     @Err INT = 0,
     @Rows INT = 0
AS 
BEGIN TRAN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @SQL = N'SET @Err = 0
                 SET @Rows = 0

                 UPDATE CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + ' COB
                 SET COB.' + @BalMonth + '  = (SELECT COB.' + @BalMonth + ' FROM CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + ' COB WHERE COB.CostCode = @OldNominal AND COB.FinPeriodNr = @FINPERIODNR) + @Amt
                 WHERE COB.CostCode = @OldNominal AND COB.FinPeriodNr = @FINPERIODNR

                 SELECT @Err = @@Error, @Rows = @@ROWCOUNT

                 UPDATE CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + ' COB
                 SET COB.' + @BalMonth + ' = (SELECT COB.' + @BalMonth + ' FROM CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + ' COB WHERE COB.CostCode = @NewNominal AND COB.FinPeriodNr = @FINPERIODNR) - @Amt
                 WHERE COB.CostCode = @NewNominal AND COB.FinPeriodNr = @FINPERIODNR

                 SELECT @Err = @@Error, @Rows = @@ROWCOUNT

                 UPDATE Posting' + @ORGCODE + ' PO
                 SET Nominal = @NewNominal
                 WHERE PO.Deleted = 0 AND PO.OrderRecNo = @InvDetailID AND PO.OrderType = ''SI''

                 SELECT @Err = @@Error, @Rows = @@ROWCOUNT;';

    -- Check if succeeded to find.
    If @Err = 0 AND @Rows > 0 
        COMMIT TRAN
    ELSE
        ROLLBACK TRAN

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@ORGCODE VARCHAR(6), @NewNominal INT, @OldNominal INT, @BalMonth CHAR(6), @Amt Decimal(12,2), @FINPERIODNR INT, @InvDetailID INT, @Err INT, @Rows INT', 
                             @ORGCODE, @NewNominal, @OldNominal, @BalMonth, @Amt,  @FINPERIODNR, @InvDetailID, @Err, @Rows;
```

Comment: MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: You have some issues here for sure. Checking @@Error and @@ROWCOUNT is getting overwritten by your third query everytime. I would split this into three dynamic sql calls instead so you can control it. Also, if you used an alias for your table your dynamic sql would be a lot simpler to read because you wouldn't have to keep appending ORGCODE on the front over and over.

Comment: @SeanLange Is it not possible to do it in a single procedure? I have a lot of scenarios where I have multiple queries in a procedure

Comment: Of course you can do it in a single procedure, you just need to break apart your queries since you want to check the rowcount of each one. Which btw you don't have to do inside the dynamic sql. I will post an example of your code shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my answer which I ended up with just in case anyone else wanted to know how I resolved it.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ASP_XXNominalBalanceUPDATE]
     @ORGCODE VARCHAR(6),
     @NewNominal INT,
     @OldNominal INT,
     @BalMonth CHAR(6),
     @Amt Decimal(12,2),
     @FINPERIODNR INT,
     @InvDetailID INT

AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET XACT_ABORT ON; --IMPORTANT TO TURN THIS ON
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

    BEGIN TRAN

        ------RUN THE 1st PROCEDURE------
        SET @SQL = N'
        UPDATE CCB
        SET CCB.' + @BalMonth + '  = (SELECT CCB2.' + @BalMonth + ' FROM CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + ' CCB2 
                                      WHERE CCB2.CostCode = @OldNominal AND CCB2.FinPeriodNr = @FINPERIODNR) + @Amt
        FROM CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + ' CCB
        WHERE CCB.CostCode = @OldNominal AND CCB.FinPeriodNr = @FINPERIODNR;';

        EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@ORGCODE VARCHAR(6), @NewNominal INT,@OldNominal INT, @BalMonth CHAR(6), @Amt Decimal(12,2), @FINPERIODNR INT, @InvDetailID INT', 
                                    @ORGCODE, @NewNominal, @OldNominal, @BalMonth, @Amt,  @FINPERIODNR, @InvDetailID; 

        ------TEST IF ANYTHING WAS UPDATED------
        IF  @@ROWCOUNT = 0 GOTO ERR_HANDLER -- IF NOT THEN ROLLBACK AND RETURN ERROR

        ------RUN THE 2nd PROCEDURE------
        SET @SQL = N'
        UPDATE CCB
        SET CCB.' + @BalMonth + ' = (SELECT CCB2.' + @BalMonth + ' FROM CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + ' CCB2 
                                     WHERE CCB2.CostCode = @NewNominal AND CCB2.FinPeriodNr = @FINPERIODNR) - @Amt
        FROM CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + ' CCB
        WHERE CCB.CostCode = @NewNominal AND CCB.FinPeriodNr = @FINPERIODNR;';

        EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@ORGCODE VARCHAR(6), @NewNominal INT,@OldNominal INT, @BalMonth CHAR(6), @Amt Decimal(12,2), @FINPERIODNR INT, @InvDetailID INT', 
                                    @ORGCODE, @NewNominal, @OldNominal, @BalMonth, @Amt,  @FINPERIODNR, @InvDetailID; 

        ------TEST IF ANYTHING WAS UPDATED------
        IF  @@ROWCOUNT = 0 GOTO ERR_HANDLER -- IF NOT THEN ROLLBACK AND RETURN ERROR

        ------RUN THE 3rd PROCEDURE------
        SET @SQL = N'
        UPDATE PO
        SET Nominal = @NewNominal
        FROM Posting' + @ORGCODE + ' PO
        WHERE PO.Deleted = 0 AND PO.OrderRecNo = @InvDetailID AND PO.OrderType = ''SI'';';

        EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@ORGCODE VARCHAR(6), @NewNominal INT,@OldNominal INT, @BalMonth CHAR(6), @Amt Decimal(12,2), @FINPERIODNR INT, @InvDetailID INT', 
                                    @ORGCODE, @NewNominal, @OldNominal, @BalMonth, @Amt,  @FINPERIODNR, @InvDetailID; 

        ------TEST IF ANYTHING WAS UPDATED------                        
        IF  @@ROWCOUNT = 0 GOTO ERR_HANDLER -- IF NOT THEN ROLLBACK AND RETURN ERROR

    COMMIT TRAN 
    RETURN 0 


ERR_HANDLER:
PRINT 'Unexpected error occurred!' --RETURN AN ERROR MESSAGE
ROLLBACK TRAN 
RETURN 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is of course completely untested but this should give you a nudge in the right direction.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ASP_XXNominalBalanceUPDATE]
     @ORGCODE VARCHAR(6),
     @NewNominal INT,
     @OldNominal INT,
     @BalMonth CHAR(6),
     @Amt Decimal(12,2),
     @FINPERIODNR INT,
     @InvDetailID INT

AS 
BEGIN TRAN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

declare @RowCount1 int
    , @RowCount2 int
    , @RowCount3 int

BEGIN TRANSACTION

BEGIN TRY
    SET @SQL = N'
    UPDATE ccb
    SET ' + @BalMonth + '  = ccb.' + @BalMonth + ' + @AMT '
    + ' FROM CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + ' ccb 
    WHERE ccb.CostCode = @OldNominal AND ccb.FinPeriodNr = @FINPERIODNR'

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@ORGCODE VARCHAR(6), @OldNominal INT, @BalMonth CHAR(6), @Amt Decimal(12,2), @FINPERIODNR INT', 
                               @ORGCODE, @OldNominal, @BalMonth, @Amt, @FINPERIODNR; 
    set @RowCount1 = @@ROWCOUNT                       


    set @SQL = N'
    UPDATE ccb
    SET ' + @BalMonth + ' = ccb.' + @BalMonth + ' - @Amt'
    + ' FROM CostCodeBalance' + @ORGCODE + ' ccb 
    WHERE ccb.CostCode = @NewNominal AND ccb.FinPeriodNr = @FINPERIODNR'

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@ORGCODE VARCHAR(6), @OldNominal INT, @BalMonth CHAR(6), @Amt Decimal(12,2), @FINPERIODNR INT', 
                               @ORGCODE, @OldNominal, @BalMonth, @Amt, @FINPERIODNR; 
    set @RowCount2 = @@ROWCOUNT                       

    set @SQL = N'
    UPDATE Posting' + @ORGCODE 
    + 'SET Nominal = @NewNominal
    WHERE Deleted = 0 AND Posting' + @ORGCODE + '.OrderRecNo = @InvDetailID AND OrderType = ''SI'''

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@ORGCODE VARCHAR(6), @NewNominal INT, @InvDetailID INT', 
                                @ORGCODE, @NewNominal, @InvDetailID; 

    set @RowCount3 = @@ROWCOUNT

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    --Add some logic here for what you want returned when an error occurs.
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

Comment: I figured it wouldn't work exactly as is but glad to know it got you going.